# com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: 401 Authorization Required

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-fabric

my app want to login with Twitter by using Fabric Android sdk

but appear

```
com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterApiException: 401 Authorization Required

com.twitter.sdk.android.core.TwitterAuthException: Failed to get request token
   at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.identity.OAuthController$1.failure(OAuthController.java:95)
at com.twitter.sdk.android.core.internal.oauth.OAuth1aService$1.failure(OAuth1aService.java:215)
```

Comment: correct system date and time work for me

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At last I found the device system date and time is not correct, when time is correct. SDK works fine! I think this reason may appear in other SDKs which work with system time.

Comment: no its not working for me. I have tried but getting same error.

Comment: So will any user that has the date incorrect on their Android phone get this error when trying to login via Twitter?

Answer (score 0):

try this

I had same problem and I solved it by the following methods
Those are

1) checked for callback URL and added extra CallBack URL i.e

> **twittersdk://**
>
> adding the above url because if we don’t have twitter app installed the twittersdk tries to open in web view so we have to add this callback url

2)Added this code before SetContentView method in onCreate

```java
//Initialize twitter SDK
TwitterConfig config = new TwitterConfig.Builder(this)
                .logger(new DefaultLogger(Log.DEBUG))
                .twitterAuthConfig(new TwitterAuthConfig(YOUR_CONSUMER_API_KEY, YOUR_CONSUMER_API_SECRET))
                .debug(true)
                .build();
Twitter.initialize(config);
```